# Having a huge issue with downloading pandas-datareader with Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

This issue has been plaguing me for a few days. After uninstalling python 3.6.2 and reinstalling python 3.6.2. I've tried to install pandas-data reader on the CMD and this is what I get.It stays like this.

I've checked various websites and youtube videos but no one has experienced this problem.

What to do? Completely new to programming.
[image]

Comment: For how long have you let it sit like that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @ifconfig I let it sit overnight- about 4 hours like that. No change.